# Displaying the current collection on a product info page (shopify liquid)

Tags: shopify, liquid

I am on the product info page and would like to know if its possible to get the current collection that the product is in so that i can do some stuff. How can i get the current collection? I have tried collection.title and it doesnt show anything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to get the CURRENT collection, you MUST have the collection handle in your URL.

So for example if the product URL is something like so `/collections/COLLECTION_HANDLE/products/PRODUCT_HANDLE` you will have access to the current collection.

In your case since you don't have access to the collection title I assume that your URL is just `/products/PRODUCT_HANDLE`.

This means that you are generating the wrong URL's ( not wrong, but not full ). You must look for `product.url` in your collection and add the filter `within: collection`.

So your collection liquid code should look something like this

```
{% for product in collection.products %}

  ... SOME OUTPUT ...
  <a href="{{ product.url | within: collection }}">Details</a>

{% endfor %}
```

This will force your product url to include the collection URL as well.

Comment: Note that a product can be in N collections. Your Liquid here, **collection.products** is a listing of the products in a collection, meaning you **know** the collection. The OP is having trouble figuring out this concept.

In other words, this answer does not really help... with the abstract cause of trying to figure out which collection a product is in. This has been a traditional nightmare with Shopify since it is marketing gold to know which collection a product sold from, and you cannot easily know that without Google Analytics type computing, which is external to Shopify itself.

Comment: @David Lazar I mentioned two times that this code is in the Collection template. Meaning that he needs to update his collection template in order to have a correct URL address to his product one. The ONLY way to know the current collection is if you come from one ( or if you set this as an option in a section or settings or hardcoded the collection URL ), you can't get the current collection ( if they are more than one ) from the `product.collections` array and I didn't say that you can. Since there is no code provided I assume he accessed the product from the collection.

Comment: Understood. It is hard to help with questions like the OP posted. Clearly there is a lack of not only basic understanding in it, no context either. So we flail away and paste obvious knowledge in the hopes it helps...

Comment: thanks figured thats how it would work, its usually from what the url path is to get other pieces of info. but it would be nice to have had the product object know the collection that its related to. maybe a future update from shopify who knows.

Comment: It seems crazy to me that a product's collections are not in the line_item object

Answer (score 1):

Try it if your URL in this format "/collections/COLLECTION_HANDLE/products/PRODUCT_HANDLE"

Try This: 
This product is in the {{ collection.title }} Collection.

Answer (score 1):

Although there might be many collections product assigned but the better way to get the current collection title that is in URL

*Note: Using this code you can do stuff on your product page only if collection is in the URL.*

```
{% assign product_collection = collection.title | link_to: product_collection.url %}
{% unless product_collection == blank %}
    <h3>Current Collection is: {{ product_collection }}</h3>
{% endunless %}
```